# addition of two vectors in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Confused about this question ..vectors in space $\mathbb{R}^2$
$$M = \{(x,y)∈ \mathbb{R}^2 | \ 0 ≤ x ≤y\}$$
$$N = \{(x,y)∈ \mathbb{R}^2 | \ 0 ≥ x ≥y\}$$

$$P= M∪N$$ ($P$ is closed under scalar multiplication)

How can I get two vectors in $P$, such that their sum is not in $P$? confused

Thank you.

Comment: $[1,1] \in M$ and $[0, -1] \in N$, but $[1,1] + [0, -1] = [1, 0]$ is not in $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, it can be extremely helpful to draw a picture. Your subspace is in grey, and we just need to find two vectors that leave the region, when added. Pictorially, that's just two vectors that form a parallelogram with one vertex outside of the region.

[image]

Comment: Note that I should have said "alleged" subspace, or "region", as of course it's not a subspace.

Answer (score 2):

$(1, 4) + (-2, -3) = (-1, 1)$ not in $P$

Comment: can you please explain this to me? thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have $(x_1,y_1) \in M, (x_2,y_2) \in N$. You can choose $x_1+x_2 >0, y_1+y_2 < 0$ , then the point $A = (x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2) \notin M\cup N$. There are plenty such points. One of them is obtained by letting $x_1 = 2, y_1 = 3, x_2 = -1, y_2 = -5 \Rightarrow x_1+x_2= 1, y_1+y_2 =-2 < 0$, and $A=(1,-2) \notin M\cup N$.